# PintOS: schedule() Kernel Panic at ASSERT(is_thread(next))

Tags: c, bochs, pintos

Schedule() in thread.c takes the current running thread and the next thread in the ready list, and does an ASSERT that the next thread is a thread (is_thread(t) checks that t != NULL and that t->magic == THREAD_MAGIC). I'm currently getting this error:

```
Kernel PANIC at ../../threads/thread.c:563 in schedule(): assertion 'is_thread(next)' failed.
```

I'm currently implementing timer_sleep so that it doesn't do busy waiting. Here is my timer_sleep function:

```
void
timer_sleep (int64_t ticks) 
{
  if (ticks > 0)
  {
    ASSERT (intr_get_level () == INTR_ON);
    enum intr_level old_level;
    old_level = intr_disable ();

    struct thread *current_thread;
    current_thread = thread_current();

    int64_t wake_tick = timer_ticks() + ticks;
    current_thread->wake_tick = wake_tick;

    list_insert_ordered (&sleep_list, &current_thread->timer_elem, cmp_wake_ticks, NULL);
    thread_block();

    intr_set_level(old_level);
  }
}
```

And my timer_interrupt:

```
static void
timer_interrupt (struct intr_frame *args UNUSED)
{
  enum intr_level old_level;
  old_level = intr_disable ();

  ticks++;
  thread_tick ();

  struct list_elem* sl_elem;
  struct thread* sl_thread;
  while(!list_empty(&sleep_list))
  {
    sl_elem = list_front(&sleep_list);
    sl_thread = list_entry(sl_elem, struct thread, timer_elem);

    if (sl_thread->wake_tick > ticks)
    {
      break;
    }

    thread_unblock(sl_thread);
    list_remove(sl_elem);
  }

  intr_set_level (old_level);
}
```

The only place where anything is being added to the ready_list is in thread_unblock, which also does an ASSERT is_thread, so I'm not sure where something that isn't a thread would ever be added to the ready list. I've not made any other changes to the base code other than adding the timer_elem to thread.h and the thread cmp_wake_ticks function.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the address of next inside of schedule() to make sure it's not NULL?

Comment: I tried adding a printf being the assertion in schedule() and, interestingly, it didn't print out at all. I then put a if (!null) statement around the assertion, and that seems to fix the assertion problem at that point in the code, but then I started getting another assertion error in thread_current(), that's complaining that thread_running() isn't running. This makes no sense, so I'm starting to think there's some strange stack overflow issue going on (as described in thread.h). Any ideas what might be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

In `list_insert_ordered()`, you use `struct elem` "timer_elem"

But see `next_thread_run()` function(call by `is_thread()`)

Implement like this

> list_entry (list_pop_front (&ready_list), struct thread, elem);

That means, blocked thread in ready_list use "timer_elem" but pop function use "elem"

**So you unify your `stuct elem` to "elem"**